# OpenIdConnect configurations with OKTA

Tags: asp.net-mvc, okta, episerver

I have a web applicaiton that uses OpenIdConnectAuthenntication. There are Maps to login and logout pages. Sample shown below for login.

```
        app.Map("/login.aspx", map =>
        {
            map.Run(ctx =>
            {
                if (ctx.Authentication.User == null || !ctx.Authentication.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                {
                    // trigger authentication
                    ctx.Response.StatusCode = 401;
                }
                else
                {
                    ctx.Response.Redirect("/");
                }

                return Task.FromResult(0);
            });
        });
```

I am trying to find a way to completely exit out of the openidconnect option and redirect user to an entirely new web application when it gets to statuscode = 401 line.

Here the aim is that I have two applications A and B. Both make use of OKTA authentication. For some reason I need the users who are coming to application A directly be redirected to B and have them login there. Once authenticated from B they will be routed to A. I need B to be the entry gate for application A.

Answer (score 1):

There is an `AuthenticationFailed` event (called Notifications) in the OpenID Owin implementation

In example

```
app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
{
      // config...
      ClientId = //...,
      ClientSecret = // ...,
      // etc

      // events
      Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
      {
      // AuthenticationFailed
            AuthenticationFailed = context =>
            {
                  context.HandleResponse();

                  // Handle redirect

                  //context.Response.Write(context.Exception.Message);
                  //_logger.Log(context.Exception.Message);
                  return Task.FromResult(0);
            },
            // ...
      }
}
```

More complete example can be found here https://github.com/EricHerlitz/Identityserver4-Episerver-Demo/blob/master/IdEpi/IdEpi.WebEpiserver/Business/Owin/Startup.cs